# How to get full path of current directory in Python2.7 in Windows?

Tags: windows, python-2.7, directory

I tried some of the answers to the existing post "How to get full path of current directory in Python?".
I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows.
If my full path is "c:\alpha\beta\gamma", i get only "gamma" and not the full path. How should I coax python on windows not to swallow the prefix?

Comment: Can we see the code you've used so far?

Answer (score 2):

This line of code should work for any file, as long as you are using Python 2.7.  Using __file__ will use the current script for the file to locate.

```
os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

The abspath() part is necessary to get the full absolute path name instead of simply the directory name.